# R Package Install Failed (suspecting bad connection?)

Tags: r, proxy

all.

When I tried to install a package, it automatically halted.

```
> install_github("knitcitations", "cboettig")
Installing github repo knitcitations/master from cboettig
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/cboettig/knitcitations/archive/master.zip
Installing package from /var/folders/4p/c5pzz4jd6zz98slzq2vc3x8w0000gn/T//Rtmp2r0xUn/master.zip
arguments 'minimized' and 'invisible' are for Windows only
Installing knitcitations
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --vanilla CMD build  \
  '/private/var/folders/4p/c5pzz4jd6zz98slzq2vc3x8w0000gn/T/Rtmp2r0xUn/devtools273458506e75/knitcitations-master' --no-manual --no-resave-data 

* checking for file '/private/var/folders/4p/c5pzz4jd6zz98slzq2vc3x8w0000gn/T/Rtmp2r0xUn/devtools273458506e75/knitcitations-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'knitcitations':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed connect to dx.doi.org:8080; Connection refused
Server error for doi http://dx.doi.org/10.1890/11-0011.1, you may want to try again.
No results
Quitting from lines 60-83 (tutorial.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'tutorial.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
argument "bibtype" is missing, with no default
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I also tried to connect with a proxy, but it still make this error.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on my machine (R version 3.1.1, Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)).

Comment: Nor can I (x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64).

Comment: If its something in the vignettes then fork it on github, comment out stuff in the vignette, try from there. The :8080 stuff looks very strange, no idea where that is coming from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the error here is coming from building vignettes, you can easily skip that part with:

```
install_github("cboettig/knitcitations", quick=TRUE)
```

Or:

```
install_github("cboettig/knitcitations", build_vignettes=FALSE)
```

See `? install` for details.

Comment: One more thing, it seems like the failure of building vignettes is coming from `Failed connect to dx.doi.org:8080; Connection refused`. I am woundering that whether I can use this package to make citations with requirement of connecting to doi.org on my machine.

Comment: @nml Give it a try. If it doesn't work, post a new question about it. Seems like it might just be a weird temporary issue, but it's hard to say.